# Is it possible to make Pretty Photo Js to show sequence of images on opening a single image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, prettyphoto, portfolio

I want to make my portfolio web page to display my graphic design works. Each work will have a cover image and more than two project images to display.

So, is that a way to customize PrettyPhoto Js to show all project images in a slide after clicking the cover image?

I've attached Image for reference.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group them using relation attribute. 
Look at the example below how I grouped first two items with rel="prettyPhoto[1] and next three with rel="prettyPhoto[2]"

```
<li class="col-sm-4"  data-filter=".photos">
<a rel="prettyPhoto[1]" href="...">
<img class="img-responsive" src="..." alt="" title=""/>
</a>
</li>
<li class="col-sm-4"  data-filter=".photos">
  <a rel="prettyPhoto[1]" href="...">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="..." alt="" title=""/>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="col-sm-4"  data-filter=".photos">
  <a rel="prettyPhoto[2]" href="...">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="..." alt="" title=""/>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="col-sm-4"  data-filter=".photos">
  <a rel="prettyPhoto[2]" href="...">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="..." alt="" title=""/>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="col-sm-4"  data-filter=".photos">
  <a rel="prettyPhoto[2]" href="...">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="..." alt="" title=""/>
  </a>
</li>
```